# how to write NSRegularExpression to xx:xx:xx?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i am trying to check if `NSString` is in specific format. **dd:dd:dd**. I was thinking of `NSRegularExpression`. Something like

`/^(\d)\d:\d\d:\d\d)$/ ?`

Comment: `[0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];

NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

(I haven't tested it, because I cannot right now, but it should be working)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/)

With this and assuming that in dd:dd:dd 'd' actually stands for a digit from 0-9 it should be fairly easy to implement what you need given the additional comment from Grijesh.

Here's an example copied from the RegexKitLite page:

```
// finds phone number in format nnn-nnn-nnnn
NSString *regEx = @"{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}";
NSString *match = [textView.text stringByMatching:regEx];
if ([match isEqual:@""] == NO) {
    NSLog(@"Phone number is %@", match);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

```
NSString *idRegex = @"[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]";
NSPredicate *idTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", idRegex];               
for (NSString * str in newArrAfterPars) {
if ([idTest evaluateWithObject:str]) {
}
}
```